# How to migrate a cached ServiceStack session to a new "version"

Tags: session, caching, servicestack

When we add new properties to our custom AuthUserSession based session DTO, we either need to invalidate users active sessions and force them to re-login, or migrate their sessions (either in mass, or in lazy fashion).  If this is not done, expected properties will not be filled, and adds a lot more complexity to the code relying on those properties.

I dug around and looked for any events around hydration of sessions from cache, but didn't see any easy place to tie in and determine if the session should be refreshed.

Any suggestions on where to plug in such logic in the flow where it will always happen before some session object is used by a ServiceStack Service or Razor view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [Caching providers that implement ICacheClientExtended](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching#icacheclientextended) you can access all Sessions with:

```
var sessionPattern = IdUtils.CreateUrn<IAuthSession>(""); //= urn:iauthsession:
var sessionKeys = Cache.GetKeysStartingWith(sessionPattern).ToList();

var allSessions = Cache.GetAll<IAuthSession>(sessionKeys);
```

Otherwise I've just added a custom hook to be able to filter a session ([in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/52123a07a75f743861e9346a5723ae9911449471)), by overriding `OnSessionFilter()` in your AppHost, e.g:

```
public override IAuthSession OnSessionFilter(IAuthSession session, string id)
{
    return base.OnSessionFilter(session, id);
}
```

This change is available from v4.0.49 that's now [available from MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: So that OnSessionFilter will be executed each time a session is pulled from its cache for use?

Comment: @JesseP yes the latest v4.0.49 will execute `AppHost.OnSessionFilter()` after it retrieves from the cache each time.